# Inheritance in interface with generics

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to migrate an application which has to read from various XML, each of them having different models and methods/stuff to do before persisting them into db.
For that reason, I've decided to create an interface `IEntityController<T> where T : PersistentEntity` and a controller implementing it for each entity (XML), this way they all can have different implementations...

```
    public interface IEntityController<T> where T : PersistentEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the data inserted into the xml is valid and all the requirements are met
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="FooValidationException">When the instance is not valid and can't be saved</exception>
    void Validate(T entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement changes in data before its saved
    /// </summary>
    void PreProcess(T entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Save or Update the entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"></exception>
    void Persist(T entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement changes in data after the entity is saved
    /// </summary>
    void PostProcess(T entity);
}
```

After that, I've got a factory method which returns the proper controller based on the xml:

```
        private IEntityController<PersistentEntity> GetController(XmlFile file)
    {
        Type fileType = file.GetType();

        if(fileType == typeof(FileBoo))
            return (IEntityController<PersistentEntity>) new BooController(DC);
      ......
    }
```

My problem is:
`BooController` implements the interface of `IEntityController<Boo>` where `Boo` inherits `PersistentEntity`, when trying to cast the controller to  `IEntityController<PersistentEntity>` I get an `InvalidCastException`, though I have no problems casting BooController to `IEntityController<Boo>`, It's like C# ignores inheritance of the generic types.

Any ideas on how to solve this/implement it better?
Thanks

Comment: I believe this has to do with [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). You cannot cast `IEntityController<Boo>` to `IEntityController<PersistentEntity>` even though `Boo`inherits `PersistentEntity`.

Comment: The `Validate` method of your `BooController` takes a `Boo`. By casting it to an `IEntityController<PersistentEntity>`, you're saying that actually you can pass in *any* `PersistentEntity`, not just a `Boo`. If you want your `Validate` method to be able to accept any `PersistentEntity`, then declare it as `Validate(PersistentEntity entity)`. If you want your `BooController` to be able to accept any `PersistentEntity`, then declare it as `class BooController : IEntityController<PersistentEntity>`

Comment: @canton7 But I want BooController:Validate to only accept Boo,thing is in my main method I need to declare it as PersistentEntity since I don't know which xml is loaded at compile-time

Comment: @acuevasdev But if it can only accept a `Boo`, then you don't want to cast it to an `IEntityController<PersistentEntity>`, because if you did that, you'd be allowed to pass in things which *aren't* instances of `Boo`

Comment: If you *need* it to be an `IEntityController<PersistentEntity>`, then you simply can't declare it as an `IEntityController<Boo>`. You'll need to declare it as something which accepts a `PersistentEntity`, then casts that to a `Boo`.

Comment: Just because two types, `T1` and `T2` exhibit a particular inheritance relationship, that does *not* mean that a generic type parameterized on those two types (`G<T1>` and `G<T2>`) will exhibit the same relationship

Comment: As @Michael said it has to do with Covariance and Contravariance, I need my interface to be covariant but I can't since my methods have arguments. I'll have to rethink this whole thing or declare all the controllers as implementations of IEntityController<PersistentEntity> and then cast the argument,which I find a pretty ugly solution. Anyways thanks to both of you

Comment: @acuevasdev From your example, you're going to need some form of runtime checking. If you didn't do it manually, some compiler would have to insert it for you. There's nothing which stops a caller from getting an `IEntityController<PersistentEntity>` and then passing in a `PersistentEntity` which *isn't* a `Boo`, so you *need* a runtime check for this. Once you accept this, the possible designs become clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to remove the generic type from IEntityController so that it looks like this:

```
 public interface IEntityController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the data inserted into the xml is valid and all the requirements are met
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="FooValidationException">When the instance is not valid and can't be saved</exception>
    void Validate(PersistentEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement changes in data before its saved
    /// </summary>
    void PreProcess(PersistentEntity  entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Save or Update the entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"></exception>
    void Persist(PersistentEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement changes in data after the entity is saved
    /// </summary>
    void PostProcess(PersistentEntity  entity);
}
```

Since your method

```
private IEntityController<PersistentEntity> GetController(XmlFile file)
```

always returns an IEntityController of PersistentEntity and not an IEntityController of T you don't need generics at all.

Remember:

```
List<string> doesn't inherit from List<object>
```

otherwise this could happen

```
public static void DestroyTheWorld(List<object> list) {
    list.add(new object());
}

public static void Main() {
    var list = new List<string>();
    DestroyTheWorld(list); //possible if list<string> inherits from list<object>
    //an object has been added to a list of string
}
```